# What is the fastest way to loop through sub dataframes in a PySpark DataFrame?

Tags: pyspark

Suppose I have a data set `df` that looks like the following:

```
 ═══════╤═════════════ 
  group │ val1   val2  
 ───────┼───────────── 
  a     │ 2      4     
  a     │ 5      3     
  b     │ 6      1     
  b     │ 8      9     
  c     │ 5      7     
  c     │ 1      2     
  c     │ 9      4     
 ═══════╧═════════════
```

but with a LOT of rows (8 billion)

My current code for processing this looks like the following:

```
iterValues = df.group.distinct().collect()
for x in iterValues:
    df2 = df.filter(df.group == x)
    data = df2.collect()
    [... some analysis ...]
```

The idea is to analyze the data for each individual group individually. The analysis involves looping through each row of `df2` (getting the `val1` and `val2` values at each row and binning them for a heat map).

The problem is that this takes a very, very long time - about 30 seconds per iteration. The part of the code that takes a long time is .collect()

I've tried toPandas(), saving the data off, using cache(), etc. Nothing really helps much.

Is there a better way to be doing this, or is the long runtime unavoidable?

Comment: instead of converting spark dataframe to a list, you can do this operation using pyspark. Would be a lot faster

Comment: how can that be done?

Comment: can you tell us more about analysis you want to do on them? because you can do a lot of thing with "groupby" and maybe you can prevent filter each group and collect

Comment: Why do you need to do .collect() to do the analysis? You can also use a Window function and use partitionBy to get rid og this loop